# git am should ignore something in commit message startswith "[]"?

Tags: git, git-am

I have a commit with message like `[Hello World]Something.`
Then I use git format-patch HEAD~1 to crate a patch.
Content of patch like this:

```
Subject: [PATCH 1/7] [Hello World] Something.
```

But after I use git am to apply patch,the commit message became "Something" only,[Hello World] seems lost.
How can I keep content in "[]" after apply patch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`git am -k` would prevent it from removing content in `[]` brackets at the beginning of the subject, but that would also keep the `[PATCH 1/7]` portion.  `git format-patch` also has a `-k` option which would prevent it from adding that type of content allowing the subject to be preserved through a `git format-patch | git am` cycle.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same concern and found the solution in the link below:

http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Bug-Incorrect-stripping-of-the-PATCH-prefix-in-git-am-td7643405.html

We have to use "am" command with "--keep-non-patch" option. The man page describes as follows:

$ man git am

```
   --keep-non-patch
       Pass -b flag to git mailinfo (see git-mailinfo(1)).
```

$ man git mailinfo

```
   -b
       When -k is not in effect, all leading strings bracketed with [ and ] pairs
       are stripped.  This option limits the stripping to only the pairs whose
       bracketed string contains the word "PATCH".
```

Comment: Nice. Looks like that was added in git 2.6.0, so wasn't available when I wrote my answer for this.

Comment: I could found it based on your answer. Thanks!